# Infinite array problem in for q number of queries

Tags: c++, arrays

Given an array, "A" of integers and you have also defined the new array"B"as a concatenation of
array"A" for an infinite number of times.
For example,if the given array"A"is[1,2,3]then,infinite array“B”is[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 ........
Now you are given q queries, each query consists of two integers"L" and"R"(1-based indexing).
Your task is to find the sum of the subarray from index"L" to"R"(both inclusive)in the infinite array "B" for each query.
Note:

```
The value of the sum can be very large,return the answer as modulus 10^9+7.
```

Input Format

```
The first line of input contains a single integer T, representing the number of test cases
or queries to be run.
Then the test cases follow.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N, denoting the size of the
array"A".
The second line of each test case contains N single space-separated integers, elements of
the array"A".
The third line of each test case contains a single integer Q, denoting the number of
queries.
Then each of the Q lines of each test case contains two single space-separated integers L,
and R denote the left and the right index of the infinite array"B" whose sum is to be
returned.
```

I have come up with an approach that doesn't think is the optimal solution for this. I have used two pointer approach in this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
vector<int> sumInRanges(vector<int> &arr, int n, vector<vector<long long>> &queries, int q) {
    // Write your code here
    vector<int> res;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        int sum = 0;
        int start = queries[i][0];
        int end = queries[i][1];
        while( start <= end ){
            if(start < arr.size()){
                sum += arr[start - 1];
            }
            else{
                int mod = start % arr.size();
                sum += arr[mod - 1];
            }
        }
        res.push_back(sum);
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Why did you tag it "java"? I feel like there should be a closed-form formula for that summation.

Comment: This feels very much like something from a so-called "competition" or "judge" site. Do note that such sites are *not* any kind of learning or teaching resource, no matter what you might have been told. All that seems to be taught by such sites are bad habits and bad (and sometimes even invalid) code.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow has now become the helpdesk for these competitive programming websites.  Those sites have question and answer forums, but it seems they are hardly ever used by the "participants".  Then when it is pointed out how bad the code is in terms of proper C++, many of those posters get angry.

Comment: This is a Math problem, not a coding problem. So you don't learn any coding by trying this.

Comment: No one starts from the top of their field everyone is trying to learn in one way or another and if someone is on the wrong track you can just guide him on the right one rather than taunting him. I am trying to prepare for my upcoming placement and learn the basics of programming through practicing questions. You all answered this question as if you haven't done this kind of question in your early days. Always remember not all one across the world have the same facility that they can ask their senior or faulty member some only have internet, So be kind if someone is in the wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think where you do the same things

Suppose A=[1,2,3], L=2, R=14
Your approach iterates over
`2,3,  1,2,3,  1,2,3,  1,2,3,  1,2`
see, how many times you iterate over the whole array?

instead, calculate `sum(A)` ONCE
then, calculate how many times it's used in the query (something like `floor(R/len(A)) - ceil(L/len(A))`)
multiply them
iterate ONCE to find missing sums (left from `L%len(A)` to `len(A)` and right from beginning to `R%len(A)`)

And don't forget about the modulo `1e9+7`

If `len(A)` and `q` get huge - save partial sums to beginning and partial sums till end once
And then retrieve them each query in constant time